# can't run on RowCommand in Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I have a gridview in my web page. I a linkbutton column. The commandName of the linkbutton column is "lbtnedit",  I want When i click the linkbutton  another tab will show detail of Resume by loading ID, but when i click linkbutton it don't run into gvresume_OnRowCommand

Thanks in advance !

Here my Grid:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpsubtabResumeList" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="settingrow">
            <div class="gSDMS_Grid">
                <asp:GridView ID="gridViewResume" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" 
                    AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="10" PagerSettings-Position="Bottom" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    CssClass="css_grid" OnItemCommand="gvresume_OnRowCommand" EnableViewState="true"
                    >                        
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass='AlternatingRowStyle' />
                    <EditRowStyle CssClass='EditRowStyle' />
                    <FooterStyle CssClass='FooterStyle' />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass='HeaderStyle' />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass='PagerStyle' HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <RowStyle CssClass='RowStyle' />
                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass='SelectedRowStyle' />
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Full Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="txt" SortExpression="Fullname">
                            <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Fullname")%></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-CssClass="edit-del accept" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate><a class="edit"  href='<%# "/FutureEmployee/PostResume.aspx?&id=" + Eval("ResumeID") %>' title="Detail">&nbsp;</a>
                            </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-CssClass="edit-del accept">
                                <ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnedit" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit_cmd" CommandArgument='<% #Eval("ResumeID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>                       
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is event

```
 protected void gvresume_OnRowCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName=="edit_cmd")
        {
            _id = new Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            Response.Redirect(SiteRoot + "/FutureEmployee/EmployeeTab.aspx#subTabViewResume");
        }
    }
```

Edit one:

when i use firebug here is content in link:

href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$aaaaaaa$bbbbbbbbbbb", ""false, "",";Clients.aspx", false, true)

I think it fine if : javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$mainContent$gridViewResume','resumeID') but i don't know how to do this ?

Comment: dont play with `__dopostback`framework is your friend. :) vladimir77 answer will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved proplem by remove all validate in my page.

Answer (score 1):

Asp:GridView hasn't event OnItemCommand.

You should use **OnRowCommand** and change signature of handler:

```
protected void gvresume_OnRowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "edit_cmd")
  {

  }
}
```